# ¿Para qué sirve el parámetro "/" al definir una función en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, parametros, python-3.8

Estaba contribuyendo a una librería en Github, y me he encontrado con el **parámetro "/"** como parámetro de una función. La función es bastante amplia y compleja, para no confundir, voy a crear una sencilla como ejemplo.

```
def funcion_suma(a, b, /, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

print(funcion_suma(1,2,3,4))
```

**Salida:** `10`

Por un segundo pensé que era un parámetro, pero no, **la función tiene 4 parámetros** *a*, *b*, *c* y *d*. La barra (/) simplemente está realizando algún tipo de operación.

Por supuesto, si definimos la función sin la barra funciona igualmente y da el mismo resultado:

```
def funcion_suma(a, b, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

print(funcion_suma(1,2,3,4))
```

**Salida:** `10`

**¿Para qué sirve este tipo de sintaxis?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Explicación del problema

**Es una nueva sintaxis** que se puede utilizar en los parámetros de la función. **Ha sido añadida en Python 3.8** por lo que no funciona en versiones anteriores.

Sirve para indicar que **algunos parámetros de la función deben ser especificados de forma  exclusivamente posicional** (postional argument) y NO pueden ser pasados como argumentos clave (keyword arguments)

En la función anterior, *a* y *b* son argumentos posicionales, mientras que *c* y *d* pueden ser argumentos clave o posicionales. **En resumen todo lo que está antes de la barra (*/*) pasa a ser un argumento solamente posicional**, el resto de argumentos después de la barra conservan el tipo de argumento que sean (posicional, clave, arbitrario).

De tal forma que si en la anterior función intentamos pasar *a* o *b* como argumentos clave, nos dará el siguiente `TypeError`:

**Input:**

```
def funcion_suma(a, b, /, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

print(funcion_suma(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4))
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: funcion_suma() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'a, b'
```

Sin embargo, si pasamos *a* y *b* como argumentos posicionales, todo está correcto, ya que han sido definidos como **exclusivamente** argumentos posicionales

**Input:**

```
def funcion_suma(a, b, /, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

print(funcion_suma(1,2,c=3,d=4))
```

**Output:**

```
10
```

### Posibles casos de uso.

- Permite a funciones que estén escritas puramente en Python emular comportamientos del lenguaje de programación `C` lo que hace que aumente la velocidad al compatibilizar código en `C` y en Python ([leer PEP399](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0399/)).
- Excluir los argumentos clave cuando el nombre de dicho parámetro no es de ayuda, por ejemplo la función builtin `len()`, es definida por Python de la siguiente forma `len(obj, /): #etc...` para no inducir con el parámetro *obj* a confusión.
- Poder usar dichos parámetros como keywords en el caso de que sea necesario en el futuro, por ejemplo:

```
def f(a, b, /, **kwargs):
    print(a, b, kwargs)

print(f(10, 20, a=1, b=2, c=3)) #Usamos el parámetro "a" y "b" como keyword ya que nunca ha sido usado antes.
```

**Output:**

```
10 20 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Toda esta información y más, se encuentra en la documentación de  propuestas de mejora para Python (PEP), en concreto en [PEP570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) y también de una forma más resumida en [What's New In Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)